# How do I Escape a Double Quote in Velocity 2.0?

Tags: java, velocity

I'm using Velocity 2.0.  I've created a method in a custom tool that finds and returns a substring between two strings.  This method takes three arguments: the initial string, a beginning subsequence, and an ending subsequence.  I've verified that this is working with unit tests.

My question is this: how do, in my velocity template, escape quotes so that I can pass in a string that contains double quotes?

My initial string `$mystr` is a json snippet and will look something like:

```
"receiver":"867-5309",
```

I'm trying to extract the `867-5309` from the string, which means that my begin string is `"receiver":"` and my end string is `",`

I've tried:

```
$stringTool.findSubstringBetween($mystr, """receiver"":"", """,")
```

and

```
$stringTool.findSubstringBetween($mystr, "\"receiver\":\", "\",")
```

but neither of these works (the first one causes a ParseErrorException, and the second yields double backslashes in the values passed to the method).

Comment: There is not Velocity 2.0 but only 1.7. Are you from the future?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try setting this

```
#set ( $d = '"')
```

Then you can use

```
${d}
```

In place of the quotation in the strings.

Comment: Thanks, this worked.  I'm able to use `$stringTool.findSubstringBetween($mystr, "${d}receiver${d}:${d}", "${d}")`